# CodeIgniter3 HMVC Routing with .htaccess not working

Tags: routes, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-hmvc

I am new to CI3 and I got really frustated spending more than one week in making the CodeIgniter3 [HMVC WireDesignz](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc)  Routing working with .htaccess and still it is not working properly.

Because there are multiple sources that can cause the error, I write you the link of my GitHub Repository https://github.com/ibudisteanu/PHP-TESTS

The behavior is super easy: I can access the following address with no errors

- http://localhost/
- http://localhost/index.php/login
- http://localhost/index.php/awesome

I get returns for the following links in my routing:

- http://localhost/login
- http://localhost/awesome

The error I get is **Not Found The requested URL /login was not found on this server.**

Comment: Have you tried basic rule [proposed on CI](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file) site?

Answer (score 1):

This is all i did to your htaccess file and its working fine in my test server

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

# NOTICE: If you get a 404 play with combinations of the following commented out lines
#AllowOverride All
#RewriteBase /wherever/ci/is
```

# RewriteBase /

```
# Restrict your site to only one domain
# Important USE ONLY ONE OF THESE OPTIONS BELOW!

# Option 1: To rewrite "www.domain.com -> domain.com" uncomment the following lines.
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Option 2: To rewrite "domain.com -> www.domain.com" uncomment the following lines.
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Option 3: Remove index.php from URL
#RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With}    !^XMLHttpRequest$
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}                ^[^/]*/index\.php [NC]
#RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$            $1 [R=301,NS,L]

# Send request via index.php (again, not if its a real file or folder)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public_html|\.txt|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|style\.css)

# deal with php5-cgi first
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_fcgid.c>

    # for normal Apache installations
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>

    # for Apache FCGI installations
    <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

I just commented `RewriteBase /`

I dont undestand what RewriteBase does so I may be wrong in my answer.

This is the .htaccess I use with HMVC and I have no problems.

```
    RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the below code in .htaccess in My HMVC CI3...its working fine on the live Server & on the localhost-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```